# What does the GeneratorFunction interface stands for in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

> The function* declaration (function keyword followed by an asterisk) defines a generator function, which returns a Generator object. [[Reference]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

But if I do:

```
const genFn: GeneratorFunction = function* () {};
```

I get:

```
Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type '() => Generator<never, void, unknown>' but required in type 'GeneratorFunction'.ts(2741)
lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts(161, 14): '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is declared here.
```

What does the GeneratorFunction interface stands for in TypeScript? Also, is there a more appropriate built-in interface for me to capture generator functions?

Comment: That's the type of the `GeneratorConstructor` which is also documented in the link that you provided. It's a different type. However, as the error indicates, typescript has correctly inferred the type of your generator and your annotation is just arguing with the language. Leave it off. In other words, your function has the type show in the error message, `() => Generator<never, void, unknown>`, but you don't need to write this out.

Comment: There's another type called `GeneratorFunctionConstructor`. Is that what you're referring to? Of course, my actual code isn't like that example. I'm using a library that expects arguments of type `GeneratorFunction` but I'm failing to construct an object that satisfies that type, which made me curious about the purpose of such interface.

Comment: You're right, I had the wrong type, I was thinking of the Constructor type. Now that you mention it however, I assume the purpose of the type is partially to describe the type of the Constructor. It's like the `Function` type and shouldn't be used directly for the same reasons

Comment: Makes sense, this interface is indeed used by the `GeneratorFunctionConstructor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a general four levels of annotations. All of these will compile without errors:

```
// Truly general
const genFnA: Function = function* () {};

// Bit less general
const genFnB: () => Generator = function* () {};

// Exact manual
const genFnC: () => Generator<never, void, unknown> = function* () {};

// Best: Use the inference
const genFnD = function* () {};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a very strange collision of how well-known Symbols and Generators were added to the Typescript type system. In the original proposal for Symbols, [Anders Hejlsberg proposed the following](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/980#issuecomment-60841971):

```
interface Object {
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}
```

which is a very reasonable way to enable everyone to set the `Symbol.toStringTag` on every object, and in fact that is how this well-known Symbol [is intended to be used](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring). For reasons I cannot reconstruct, this was however not added to the `Object` interface and not even to the `Function` interface, but *only* to the `GeneratorFunction` interface. Thus functions are not assignable to generator functions, though they are actually equivalent (both can be called).

The second strange thing here is that a `function*` expression evaluates to `() => Generator` and not to `GeneratorFunction`. One should assume that those are equivalent, though due to the missing `Symbol.toStringTag` they aren't.

Thus we cannot assign `function*`s to `GeneratorFunction`, although they are supposed (and actually are) describing the same type, which makes the `GeneratorFunction` interface pretty much useless.

This is either a result of various constraints I do not see, or a bug in the Typescript types.

Comment: I'm voting bug. Even if it's due to real constraints, the result is that the interface is not actually usable as it should be. Thus, resulting in erroneous compilation error.

Comment: @vlaz I opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45146)

Comment: I gave it a  - I know MS care about those when looking at what to fix.